# What is the use of the fourth leg, the one with igbt in series with the diode, in the infineon power module?

Tags: igbt

The circuit shown below is the schematic of infineon PIM module. I am specifically interested in FP15R12W1T4. From the schematic I could understand all elements other than the 4th leg which has an igbt in series with a diode. I am new to this field. I assume, that leg and terminals are provided to feedback the present voltage level under a specified switching frequency.

[image: Infineon EasyPIM]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By applying a DC shunt to the battery, the motor instead of free wheeling can regenerate and brake the motor. using the back EMF of the motor/generator.

There are different implementations including Battery Regen and single phase Remanence braking.

This is why there is a single B phase brake on a 3 phase UVW phase rectifier or bridge driver.

Comment: So, is it possible to use the B phase to establish dynamic braking or plugging?

Comment: That’s what its for